# Small glitch but could be an important issue

Tags: javascript, php, events, if-statement, handler

I currently have an issue with my drop down menu using JavaScript/AJAX and PHP.

Here's the code for the edit.php file which is supposed to retrieve data from multiple selection boxes in a drop-down list:

```
    <td ><input readonly type="text" id="mainlines" value='<?php echo $_SESSION["mainlines"];?>' name="mainlines"/> </td>
<td ><input readonly type="text" id="categories" value='<?php echo $_SESSION["categories"]; ?>' name="categories"/> </td>

<td>
<select name="subcategories" id="menu" onChange="SelectAccountHead_Code(this.value)">
<option  value="<?php print $subcategories; ?>"><?php print $subcategories; ?></option>
<?php

$sql1a = "SELECT * FROM subcategory ORDER BY subcategories asc";
$smt1a = $dbs->prepare($sql1a);
$smt1a -> execute();
while($row1a=$smt1a->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
if($row1a['subcategories']==$_GET['id2'] )
echo ("<option selected value=$row1a[subcategories]>$row1a[subcategories]</option>");
else
echo ("<option value=$row1a[subcategories]>$row1a[subcategories]</option>");
}
?>
</select>
</td>
```

For the "mainlines" and "categories", I get the data showing output only when it is selected, but when the item is being edited it doesn't automatically print it out unless I use "print $mainlines" or "print $categories".

How do I insert the `onChange` event changer in the if/else statement?

I want it to state the following in pseudo-code:

```
    if (onChange = "SelectAccountHead_Code(this.value)"){
    print $mainlines;

    } else {
    echo $_SESSION["mainlines"];

}
```

How do I go about inserting the correct syntax in the if/else clause with regards to the JavaScript/AJAX event changer/handler?

Update:

Here's my JavaScript code - where am I missing the AJAX code?

```
function SelectAccountHead_Code(i)
{
var k=document.getElementById("menu").selectedIndex;
var l=document.getElementById("menu1").selectedIndex;

if((k>0)&&(l>0))
{
self.location="edit3.php?productsnames=<?php print $productsnames;?>&id="+document.getElementById("menu").options[k].value+"&id2="+document.getElementById("menu").options[k].innerHTML +"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].value+"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].innerHTML;
}
}


function SelectAccountHead_Codes(j)
{
var k=document.getElementById("menu").selectedIndex;
var l=document.getElementById("menu1").selectedIndex;
if((k>0)&&(l>0))
{
self.location="edit3.php?productsnames=<?php print $productsnames;?>&id="+document.getElementById("menu").options[k].value+"&id2="+document.getElementById("menu").options[k].innerHTML +"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].value+"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].innerHTML;

}
}

function SelectUp(i)
{
var k=document.getElementById("menuUp").selectedIndex;
var l=document.getElementById("menuUp").selectedIndex;
self.location="edit3.php?id="+document.getElementById("menuUp").options[k].value+"&id2="+document.getElementById("menu").options[k].innerHTML +"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].value+"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].innerHTML;
}

function SelectUp(j)
{
var k=document.getElementById("menuUp").selectedIndex;
var l=document.getElementById("menuUp").selectedIndex;
self.location="edit3.php?id="+document.getElementById("menuUp").options[k].value+"&id2="+document.getElementById("menu").options[k].innerHTML +"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].value+"&id3="+document.getElementById("menu1").options[l].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant combine Javascript and PHP without further requests (Ajax) and server interaction.

Other big mistake:

```
echo ("<option selected value=$row1a[subcategories]>$row1a[subca.........
```

you have `constants` in your associative arrays.

[See this example](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/proper-inline-php-variable-concatenation/) why this is wrong:

```
$array = array('test' => 111);
define('test', 999);

echo $array[test];
```

proper:

```
echo ("<option selected value='" . $row1a['subcategories'] . "'>" . $row1a['su..
// consider adding htmlspecialchars() or addslashes() to your output
```

More minor mistakes / bad practice:

- `onChange` should be all small letters: `onchange`
- `if .. else` block should have `{` `}`

Comment: I hope subcategories don't have spaces in their name! Might want to wrap those in single-quotes. Another alternative is to use braces around the array element as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). However, doing it the way you are is certainly the clearer way (and better for a beginner to understand)